# Can I use the internal autofocus (AF) beam with an external flash on a Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, flash, camera-settings, canon-600d, focus-assist

If we are using an external third-party flash with no auto focus beam support, is there a setting to use the built-in auto focus beam with an external flash?

I'm using a [Canon EOS 600D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_600D).

Comment: I agree with @nir's answer below. As an alternative i take a torch or led keyring light to illuminate the subject while focussing  to avoid the need.

Comment: Just make sure you keep focus lock and exposure lock separated if you use this technique.

Answer (score 7):

No

The 600D uses the built in pop-up flash for the focus assist light, the pop-up flash pops up too close the the external flash if one is connected - there are many external flashes and accessories that would be hit by the popup flash if it tried to open when they are connected.

So, as a safeguard the camera will not open the popup flash if there is something in the hot shoe.

And, since the auto focus assist light is actually the pop-up flash and you can't open it with an external flash attached there isn't any way to use the auto-focus assist with an external flash.